# Pull Latest Build From Repository

Tags: java, linux, docker, shell

I have 2 projects. lets say projectA & projectB.
projectB requires projectA build.

So from projectB there is a shell script which download latest build of projectA from my artifactory.
wget http:///projectA-234.zip.

The name of projectA build is like projectA-234.zip, next build will be projectB-235.zip & so on

So eaxh & every time I need to go to projectB and update the projectA build no. i.e., from
wget http:///projectA-234.zip.
to
wget http:///projectA-235.zip.

I want to avoid this and I always want to fetch the latest build. How can I do that.
I dont want to change the name format of projectA build.i.e., the name will always be projectA-236.zip, projectA-237.zip & so on.

Comment: Did you try Maven or Gradle for your project? If you have an Artifactory, this might be the easiest way to accomplish this.

Comment: This command is present in Dockerfile. And Docker build is executed using maven exec plugin

Comment: So projectA is a runtime dependency of projectB?

Comment: yes...
In the dockerfile of projectB I am executing
RUN wget http://<artifacturl>/projectA-236.zip
The numeric part is updated on every latest projectA build and project B needs the latest build

Comment: Is it possible to include projectA directly in the Maven build and not later in the Dockerfile? It is a little hard to help without understanding the dependencies between both projects.

Comment: I think no...because it is only zip file and it is not maven project.

Comment: which Arifactory you are using?

Answer (score 0):

The Docker way to do this during `image` build time is to use an `ARG` with the version number:

**Dockerfile:**

```
...

ARG PROJECTA_VERSION
# if you need this later at container runtime
# ENV ENV_PROJECTA_VERSION=$PROJECTA_VERSION

RUN wget http://<artifacturl>/projectA-${PROJECTA_VERSION}.zip

...
```

**Docker CLI**:

```
...

export PROJECTA_VERSION=236
docker build --build-arg PROJECTA_VERSION (...)

# or (without export)
docker build --build-arg PROJECTA_VERSION=236 (...)

...
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg

But maybe this is not strictly a Docker question and you rather need something like a `latest` release (with a corresponding, always the same url `/releases/latest`):

https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/administering-a-repository/linking-to-releases